# How can I edit the key of Map in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

for example I want to edit the key that is 2 in this map and make it 3, how can I do that?

```
Map<Integer,Integer>map=new HashMap<>();
map.put(2,2);
map.get(2)=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You would have to remove the old entry with the old key and add a new one with the new key but the same value

```
Map<Integer,Integer>map=new HashMap<>();
map.put(2,2);
var removed = map.remove(2);
map.put(3, removed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code says that what you want to do is like `map.get(2) = 3`, which isn't rewriting the key -- it's updating the value for the key 2.

To do that, you just need `map.put(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maps have unique keys. You simply need to write:

```
map.put(2, 3);
```

to change your value for key=2;